# A question about a limit in a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $H$ is a Hilbert space, $v_{n},z \in H$ and suppose that

$$ \lim\langle x, v_{n}\rangle = \langle x, z \rangle$$

for all $x$ in some dense subset of $H$. Then can I say that the sequence $v_{n}$ converges to $z$?

Note: $v_{n}$ is not given to be convergent.

Comment: No. Let $v_n$ be the $n$'th unit vector in $\ell_2$ and $z=0$.

Comment: and what are $x$?

Comment: Any element of $\ell_2$.

Comment: Yeah. It will work in $l_{1}$ also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; the classic example is the space $L^2([0,2\pi])$ with $v_n=\sin(nx)$, $z=0$, and $x$ being any function in $L^2$ and $L^1$. This is known as the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma).